# Is jquery dialog ui css editable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using the jquery library which I call from the google code base. My questions is, how can I style say a dialog title bar if the code is not part of my local setup? I would be grateful if someone could explain if there is a way to style dialog using it the way I am. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. jQuery UI allows for theming. You can implement your own themes or override the base one by switching to any of the predefined themes.

The best place to learn more would by their documentation site: http://jqueryui.com/docs/Theming

You can even use this online [Themeroller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/) application to create or own themes in a jiffy.

Answer (score 1):

You can set `classes` using `dialogClass` and them use CSS to style accordingly.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#option-dialogClass

Answer (score 1):

To prevent further confusion, when you use a jquery library from a CDN (like google's), you are just making it so that people can load that file faster than if they were to load it from your site.

That file holds all the functionality, but all the styles are not stored in that file, they are still defined by your site using CSS.